# React Native: Popup menu like dev menu

Tags: react-native

in my app I wanna have a pop up menu that looks like the dev menu, and I wonder if there is a component / module that I can use to get a similar menu in react native or do I have to build it from scratch?

Thanks :)

[image: Dev Menu]

Comment: It's called an Action Sheet

Comment: @RRikesh that's what I was looking for... thanks 

Answer (score 0):

you can use NativeBase  ActionSheet component
check it [doc](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#accordion-custom-header-content-headref) for more info

Comment: Hi, please avoid answer with code only. Add some explanations about your solution .